# Cron Job uses old non-existent php file

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii, cron

I'm working with **Yii** and have to implement a script for cron.
I've got a script file, which just calls Yii and starts my php-script file.

Until this point everything is fine. If I'm updating the php-script, Cron just continues executing the old one.

Restart of cron-service, reboot of the server etc didn't help.
I also uninstalled cron and installed it again, but nothing changed. He still executes the old version of this php-script.

Anyone an idea what's wrong or what I could do to solve this? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

**EDIT:**

The `cronjob` script is running:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ../www/protected/ ./yiic Cron ProcessPayments
```

The php-script

```
class CronCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
public function actionProcessPayments() {
...
}}
```

This works, but any change I make on this script is ignored by Cron.
And now I'm on this point: he executes both. My old version and the new version. I've never been this confused by something.

Comment: Can you post how you define command to run?

Comment: Did you try to run "$ crontab -l" yet?

Comment: crontab -l just prints the config you can edit with crontab -e. I've added the cron script and an excerpt of the php script.

Comment: what if you empty Yii cache and assets folders?

Comment: Have you tried Supervisor http://supervisord.org/installing.html

Comment: I have no clue, but maybe you should check for things like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work/708077

Comment: Have you tried using fully qualified file names everywhere? In other words, since this is a mystery, spell out the complete directory name of the scripts you want to use. In the crontab, spell out the full directory of the top level script you are calling. In the top level script, spell out the full directory of the PHP script.

Normally, this would not be needed, but you could try this temporarily just to establish which scripts you are using.

Comment: I'm not familiar with yii, but given the parameter 'cron', is there a php app running in the background as a cron deamon?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have sudo on the machine it's located on...

First check to see if it's located in the usual cron directories /etc/cron.*

```
sudo find /etc/cron* -mount -iname yiic
```

If nothing shows up there then search the entire filesystem because otherwise you'll start having to search a lot of other places manually and it takes more time than running a find

```
sudo find / -mount -iname yiic
```

In both find commands if the filename is or has ever been anything other than yiic do yiic* so that it searchs for anything that starts with yiic

Once you have found the copies, if there are any others, remove every single one except the newest one, or even that one and then reinstall the script on the machine from version control.

---

**Edit:**

Probably more than you really care about, but the find command breaks down like this:

`sudo` - elevated priviledges so you can search everywhere as opposed to where you're user can read

`find` - command to look for thigs

`/` - the starting point for the search, can be anywhere

`-mount` - this tells find not to search other filesystems

`-iname` - case insensitive name to search for

`yiic` - the search term

Answer (score 0):

Locate all your copies of the script using the `find` command and delete those copies not needed.  Restart `cron` after you have chosen the copy of the script you want to execute.  My guess is a copy of the script might be hanging around in a directory (e.g. `config.daily` or something similar).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. A script in /etc/cron.d was still executed in the old fashion after modifying it. I solved the problem by sending a SIGHUP to cron:

```
sudo pkill -SIGHUP /usr/sbin/cron
```